# Confusion about linear algebra syntax in python

Tags: python, linear-algebra

Please let me know if I'm in the right place.  This is my first time here.

In the "else" part, can you please let me know what the "for v in xc" part means, particularly in contrast with the dot products a few lines above it and what role the backslash after "fact" plays?

In the len = 1 case we are dotting a vector with a matrix, which is not actually a dot product but matrix multiplication.  But, I guess numpy.dot allows for it.  For the else case, is it treating row (or column?) vectors in xc one at a time to leave a vector (instead of a scalar as in the len = 1 case)?  And, if so, does that mean that numpy.dot allows for vector times matrix but not matrix times matrix?

```
def pdf(x,mu,sigma):
    d=np.alen(mu)
    dfact1=(2*np.pi)**d
    dfact2=np.linalg.det(sigma)
    fact=1/np.sqrt(dfact1*dfact2)
    xc=x-mu
    isigma=-0.5*np.linalg.inv(sigma)
    if len(np.shape(x)) == 1:
      return fact*np.exp(np.dot(np.dot(xc, isigma),xc))
    else:
      return fact\
        *np.exp(
            [np.dot(np.dot(v, isigma),v) for v in xc]
        )
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should avoid asking multiple things in one question.

Comment: where do you find `np.shape(x) == 1` in your posted code? I only find `len(np.shape(x)) == 1` which I suspect answers your question once you have looked at the docs for np.shape...

Comment: @khelwood thanks I'll take out the first one, especially since ahed87 made me realize I missed len somehow.

Comment: @ahed87  Thanks!  I must be pretty tired to have missed len somehow.

Comment: no worries, happens to all of us, and surprisingly frequently

Comment: the backslash is just line-continuation in python, used frequently in old py2 code, I prefer just wrapping too long lines in parenthesis nowadays

Comment: the shape check is for vector or matrix (suppose 2d), so with the vector there is no need to do the loop and thus coded differently, in reality I suppose they could have done without this check, pretty sure the code would have worked with only doing the loop regardless of dimension of `x`

Comment: if you want to understand the code I would just call this function and use a debugger to step through the different lines when using different input data, i.e. `x` as 1d or 2d